# S3 class Generic and Specific functions

Tags: r, function

I want to transform some data from within a list of objects. 
I created a generic function and specific functions within so that it will use the right functions according to the class of object. But it doesn't seem to route from the generic to the specific function. It works if I type out specific function, but than it defeats the purpose of having a generic function in the first place.

Please help.

```
names <- c("Astro","Barnstormer", "Big Railroad","Buzz", "Soak Station", "Cin.       Castle", 
       "Jamboree", "Dumbo", "Enchanted", "Haunted Mansion", "Jungle Cruise", "Mad Tea", 
       "Aladdin", "Winnie","Monsters, Inc", "Peter Pan", "7 Dwarfs", "Space Mountain")

Letters <-  LETTERS[1:20]

#Giving it different classes
items <- list(names=names, letters=Letters)
class(items$names) <- append(class(items$names), "names ")
class(items$letters) <- append(class(items$letters), "letters")
class(items) <- append(class(items),"items") 

# Generic method
setNames <- function(x, newValue)
{
   print("Find the correct method")
   UseMethod("setNames", x)
 }

#Default method
 setNames.Default <- function(x)
{
   print("You got it wrong")
   return(x)
}

#Specific method to class
 setNames.names <- function(x, newValue)
 {
    x$names <- newValue
    return(x)
 }

  # This works
 t <- setNames.names(items, "abc")
  # This doesn't work. 
 t <- setNames(items, "abc")
```

Comment: (1) You have a trailing space in `"names "`; (2) you are *appending* new class attributes instead of *prepending* them (R will dispatch based on the *first* matching class, not the *last*); and (3) you are calling the `setNames` generic on a `list` object. Try using `class(items) <- c("names", class(items)); setNames(items, "abc")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the class of `items` to `c("names", "list")` and made a couple changes to your functions.  Does this do what you intend?

```
#Giving it different classes
items <- list(names=names, letters=Letters)
class(items) <- c("names", "list")

"setNames" <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("setNames")
}


setNames.names <- function(x, newValue) {
  x$names <- newValue
  return(x)
}

setNames.default <- function(x, ...)
{
   warning("unknown class")
   return(x)
}

# This works
t <- setNames.names(items, "abc")

# Check if it works 
t2 <- setNames(items, "abc")

identical(t, t2)
[1] TRUE
```

And a case where it doesn't work

```
foo <- items
class(foo) <- "list"

setNames(foo, "abc")
$names
 [1] "Astro"             "Barnstormer"       "Big Railroad"     
 [4] "Buzz"              "Soak Station"      "Cin.       Castle"
 [7] "Jamboree"          "Dumbo"             "Enchanted"        
[10] "Haunted Mansion"   "Jungle Cruise"     "Mad Tea"          
[13] "Aladdin"           "Winnie"            "Monsters, Inc"    
[16] "Peter Pan"         "7 Dwarfs"          "Space Mountain"   

$letters
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
[20] "T"

Warning message:
In setNames.default(foo, "abc") : unknown class
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: We Sam's have to stick to together!